# Robust optimization for IP formulation

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, reference-request, literature-research, robust-optimization, uncertainty

I am researching the robust version of a problem. I have managed to produce an Integer programming formulation which solves the problem with perfect knowledge. From my research on the topic one can define uncertainty of the parameters by defining the uncertainty to come from a well-known uncertainty set. (e.g. Box, Interval, Ellipsoid) I am very new to this topic and most of the resources that I found online are not very helpful.

Can you recommend me a starting point (articles, papers, books repositories) that is more beginner level in this area?

Comment: Check robust optimization from Wolfram.

Comment: You may join a seminar online at https://www.ise.ufl.edu/events/graduate-seminar-series-dr-john-hasenbein/

Answer (score 5):

I think this is a relatively easy but still general paper to start with: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.02634.pdf

Answer (score 2):

you may check this https://pubs.acs.org/doi/full/10.1021/ie200150p ,there are two other papers related to that, II and III, I hope you will find it useful.